# CSS3 - Rotate to an additional amount of degrees

Tags: css, rotation

I have a pager for jQuery cycle, which I want to rotate on the active class.

I've managed it but want to know if there is a way to rotate to "+180deg" rather than "180deg" to make all the rotations look more unique.

Yes, I have tried +180deg already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By 'rotate to "+180deg' I assume you want to increment the current rotation by 180 degrees modulo 360?

Since you're using jQuery already, try the following:

```
 var self = $(this);
 var currentRotation = self.css('rotate').match(/([-.\d]+)deg/)[1];
 var newRotation = (parseInt(currentRotation, 10) + 180) % 360;
 self.css('rotate', newRotation + 'deg');
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I kinda wanted a css3 thing, trying to limit the javascript behaviour.

Comment: @joe AFAIK there's nothing in CSS that will enable you to do this, a relative change can only be done via javascript.